# Should I define a alias for my controllers?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I get a instance for all controllers by calling getController on the application instance which seems not to use the alias. But I found examples where the alias is set on some where it isn't set.

**So is it recommend to define a alias for my controllers or can/should I spare this property?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should be able to answer this question yourself...

Based on the structure of a MVC project in ExtJS and the way controller get invoked you should never need a alias and the `getController()` method doesn't use one. So you can spare these lines.

But if you like it you can define one, I don't think that there is any recommendation that can be given for pro and con beneath that you don't need it.